# Bring up a dialog box while page reloads at back?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup, modal-dialog

I'm currently using [SweetAlert](http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert), and while we are developing happily with it, we come across a situation which it doesn't cut it.

When a user finishes something on a page, the dialog box pops out. All nice. But we want the page at the back to be redirected to another page, of which the refresh will destroy the alert box.

Are there any solutions out there which can do this and provide similar features?

Below is the code to bring up the SA box:

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
type: 'post',
data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(json) {
  $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

  if (json['error']) {
    if (json['error']['option']) {
      for (i in json['error']['option']) {
        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
      }
    }

            if (json['error']['profile']) {
                $('select[name="profile_id"]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['profile'] + '</span>');
            }
  } 

  if (json['success']) {

        swal({
            title: "Success!",
            text: json['success'],
            type: "success",
            confirmButtonText: "Cool",
            confirmButtonColor: "1bbc9b",
            html: true
        });


    $('.success').fadeIn('slow');





    $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

    $('#cart-total', window.parent.document ).html(json['total']);

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
  } 
}
});
});
```

While in the backend the controller will redirect the web browser to the Cart Summary page after clicking the Add To Cart button. This is a custom code change.

Comment: We need to see the code you used.

Comment: I see. We are integrating sweetalert with OpenCart. The sweetalert code is called in a JavaScript function when something is done on the web browser and the server returns with a JSON.  Should I provide that block of front end code?

Comment: please share your code in question with some more details